# Out of memory exception in Soft Artisans Excel Writer

Tags: officewriter

I am using Soft Artisans Excel Writer to populate an excel template via binding.  When my data source (data reader) exceeds about 120000 rows I get an "Out of Memory" exception from excel writer.  Originally I was using  a datatable as the source but switched to a reader in the believe it may have a lesser memory footprint.  This does not happen all the time but often enough to be annoying. The data does have some varchar(max) in it but I have restricted all columns to 20000 characters.  I am using the latest version (as at 11 Feb 2014).  Does any one know of any tricks to minimise the load on excel writer?  Thanks

Comment: A few questions: You mentioned the number of rows, but how many columns are there?  That will give us the total number of cells.  How much RAM is on this server? What is the OS?  Is this a web application?  Is the application 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: One more question - is this an .xlsx (OOXML) or .xls (binary) file?

Comment: The exel template has 32 columns in .xlsx format.  The server OS is win 2003 server R2, server config is amd quad core with 32gb Ram.  The box also runs sql server 2008 and iis - the affected application is asp.net 4.5.  IIS and Database are one the same box for this app.  Thanks!

Comment: @Programnik - Did you ever receive a solution to this issue?

Comment: No I didnt.  Its just a memory issue unfortunately and on a larger box the issue is less prevalent.  I guess the moral of the story is don't create list reports with too many rows.